# Anime with floating house, fliers and conscripted teen boy

Tags: story-identification, space, anime, cartoon, mecha

I watched this anime/cartoon in 2010 - 2011. The main character was a teen boy. Apparently he lived in a house with his mother and his little sister (?) which was located on a floating piece of land (floating in mid-air). One day the boy was taken by some people in flying vehicles because of something his mother did (?) or because he needed to fight for them against others. I think his mother fell on her knees when they took him away and she was crying. The other scene I remember was him racing with a girl which apparently he liked, on those flying vehicle things, and she won. This anime/cartoon might fit in the category of mecha and/or space. Also I watched it on a Macedonian TV channel called Kanal 5.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/230791/animated-series-where-people-live-in-the-sky (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

Could this be Skyland?  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyland):

> It is the 23rd century; the Earth has shattered into billions of pieces which orbit around a central core. In this new world named Skyland, an evolved form of humans has appeared: Seijins, who are able to absorb energy from sunlight and use it to fuel special abilities such as telekinesis, telepathy, mental control, astral projection, energy balls or blasts and electricity rays.
>
> The Skyland is ruled by the Sphere, an organization which controls the fragmented blocks water supplies and maintains its power thanks to Guardians - promising Seijin children who have been taken away from their families and given a special training. This dictatorship is fought by pirates.
>
> After the capture of their mother by the Sphere, Mahad and Lena, a young Seijin still learning to control her powers, are rescued by a group of pirates. They join the pirate rebellion, determined to free their mother and help bring the Sphere down.

Comment: It sounded like the OP wasn't too sure of all the details.  This sounded vaguely similar to me.  It immediately popped into my mind with:

Comment: Sounded like the OP wasn't too sure of all details. This sounded vaguely similar to me and popped into my mind. 1-mother, main character (boy) and sister. Skyland starts with the mother Mila, Mahad and Lena  2-living on floating piece of land.  This is the environment..."the Earth has shattered into billions of pieces which orbit around a central core" 3-fight against others...the Sphere and Telekinesis 4-racing flying vehicles against girl he liked...other characters in the rebellion...Dahlia was her name 5-something his mother did...she was part of Sphere, left before giving birth to Lena

Comment: Also, this was a worldwide preview that occurred in 2006.  This means that it's possible that it was seen in Macedonia in 2011.