# Animated series where people live in the sky

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was drawn in the anime style but I don't know for sure if it was true anime or a western imitation—it appeared to be CGI rather than hand-drawn. It appeared on Teletoon at least in the 2000's, possibly the 2010's. It was a series, all dialogue was in English. Presumably set in the future, no nations we would recognize in the present. Basically people live their lives on permanently flying cities or ships (they're wholly artificial, not flying continents or islands or anything like that), and the heroes rebel against a corrupt regime that unfairly taxes the people for food and resources. I wish I could give you more details but this is as much as I remember.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @Valorum- I added some details from your checklist, for what little that's worth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apart from the "wholly artificial" part, this sounds very much like [Skyland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyland).

1. **CGI** -  yes
2. **On Teletoon** - yes
3. **in the 2000s** - original run from 2005 to 2007
4. **people live their lives on permanently flying cities or ships (they're wholly artificial, not flying continents or islands or anything like that)** -  not quite, while there are a multitude of flying ships, the land is actually floating pieces of the earths crust
5. **heroes rebel against a corrupt regime that unfairly taxes the people for food and resources** - water supply is run by a dictatorship called the "Sphere" who are opposed by a group of pirates rebelling against their practices.

[image]

Additional tidbits that may help confirm or dismiss this being the correct answer.

> In this new world, named Skyland, an evolved form of human has
> appeared: Seijins, who absorb energy from sunlight and use it to fuel
> special abilities such as telekinesis, telepathy, mental control,
> astral projection, energy balls or blasts, and electric rays.
>
> …
>
> After the capture of their mother by the Sphere, protagonists Mahad
> and Lena, a young Seijin still learning to control her powers, are
> rescued by a group of pirates, and join the pirate rebellion.