# Girl tries to rescue her abducted mother who is telekinetic

Tags: story-identification, animation

A long time ago, probably more than 10 years, I came across an animated series. Main character was a black haired girl, her mother was abducted by strangers in some kind of space ship.

She also had a brother. However if I recall correctly, only females could use powers. They tried rescuing her but failed because their mom sent them flying away using telekinesis. (It happened when she was abducted and then when they tried rescuing her again).

Comment: Welcome to SF&F.  Just a quick question -- what is a "space shift"?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/230791/animated-series-where-people-live-in-the-sky

Answer (score 3):

Could this be ***[Skyland](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0457541/)*** (2005–2007)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyland):

> *Skyland* (full French title: "Skyland, Le Nouveau Monde", or "Skyland, The New World"), is a CGI animated series developed in France in partnership with Canada and Luxembourg for television channels France 2 in France, Teletoon in Canada, Nicktoons in the United States, ABC in Australia and CITV in the United Kingdom. The show is a co-production between Paris's Method Films and Toronto's 9 Story Entertainment.

> Prior to the beginning of the story, in the 23rd century, the Earth has shattered into billions of pieces which orbit around a central core. **In this new world, named Skyland, an evolved form of human has appeared: Seijins, who absorb energy from sunlight and use it to fuel special abilities such as telekinesis, telepathy, mental control, astral projection, energy balls or blasts, and electric rays.**
>
> The Skyland is ruled by the Sphere: an organization which controls the water supplies, and maintains its power by Guardians, Seijins indoctrinated and trained from childhood. This dictatorship is fought by pirates. **After the capture of their mother by the Sphere, protagonists Mahad and Lena, a young Seijin still learning to control her powers, are rescued by a group of pirates, and join the pirate rebellion.**

The main characters are Lena, a black-haired girl with powers including telekinesis, and her older brother, Mahad, who doesn't have these powers. In the first episode, their mother, Mila, who has the same powers as Lena, is taken prisoner by the antagonists, an organisation known as the Sphere.